# Redirect a search to a Google Search Appliance result page

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-search-appliance

I have a homepage with a search button that currently directs users to Google's generic Search Appliance (GSA) result page, but I'd like to wrap the results into a custom HTML page without using XSLT.

I've looked around the web and heard that it can be done using JavaScript or server-side scripting. I know there’s an iFrame solution too; however, it’s only a solution when you use the search field in the same page of the iFrame.

Since I don't have access to the back-end server, I'd rather do this on the front-end, either in JavaScript, or some other script. I can't seem to find any examples in Google's documentation on how to do this.

Does anyone have some examples on how this might look like?

Comment: Do you have access to the GSA to edit the XSLT of a frontend?

Comment: You can have your javascript or a script to read the XML output (instead of HTML) and show it in your own results page. - https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/614/xml_reference#results_format

Comment: @TanHongTat thanks for the link! I've checked it out. Theoretically, what you suggest makes sense; however, I'm having a difficult time finding examples on "how" in Google's world-class documentation.

Comment: @BigMikeW I do, but when place the header/footer HTML code, the css conflicts with the XSLT and the layout gets skewed... especially the footer.

Comment: @BigMikeW I think you're right ... was just hoping to avoid option 2, since the GSA doesn't allow you to trouble shoot the header/footer code easily. I found that once I clicked on the "edit xslt" in order to see what's conflicting, I had to rollback to default … otherwise the GSA locks you into XSLT mode from the dashboard, which is poor UX on Google, btw.

Comment: @Paul Yeah the UI "Editor" only covers a few options, once you edit the XSLT directly it's too hard for it to keep tabs on whether you've changed the related values.
Honestly though, the XSLT might look scary but once you've spent an hour or two with it it's not so bad and gives you a lot of flexibility.

Would you mind accepting my answer if you're happy with it?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a couple of options:

1. In your form action (ie what happens when you submit the search) you can use the URL parameters to point at a specific front end on the GSA but do **not** include the proxystylesheet parameter. This will then return you the plain XML and you can do with it as you see fit (the contents of this XML are well documented)
2. Fix your original issue and include your header and footer in the XSLT

Bear in mind that with #1 it's harder to include some of the nicer GSA UI features such as doc preview and dynamic navigation in your results.
If CSS conflicts are your only worry with #2 I'd personally spend my time trying to fix those.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you do not have access to a backend server, but can you make a reverse proxy on your webserver?  (i.e. `http://yoursite/search -> http://yourgsa/search`)

using a proxy and some javascript is the best way.  You can't really consume XML/jSON from the GSA via Javascript any other way cross site.

There is a stylsheet which will transform the results into json/jsonp:

https://github.com/steveathon/GSJSON

But the GSA doesn't emit all of the headers that make this work well.